# Why won't my custom S3 class object append to a list in R?

Tags: r, list, oop

I am learning how to make custom S3 classes in `R` and have run into a head scratcher.

After creating an instance of my custom S3 class, it will not append to a `list` with `c()`. No warning or error is shown, it simply does not append and I do not know why.

IN:

```
# initialize a list and observe expected results
    my_list <- list()

my_list
```

OUT:

```
list()
```

IN:

```
# Append to the list with c() as per usual and observe expected results
    my_list <- c(my_list, 1)

my_list
```

OUT:

```
[[1]]
[1] 1
```

IN:

```
my_list <- c(my_list, 2)

my_list
```

OUT:

```
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2
```

IN:

```
# Define my custom S3 class
    my_custom_s3_class <- function(attribute1, attribute2) {
        my_custom_s3_class <- structure(list(), class = "my_custom_s3_class")
        attributes(my_custom_s3_class)$attribute1 <- attribute1
        attributes(my_custom_s3_class)$attribute2 <- attribute2
        my_custom_s3_class
    }

# Define print method for my S3 class
    print.my_custom_s3_class <- function(x, ...) {
        cat(attributes(x)$attribute1, attributes(x)$attribute2)
    }

# Create an instance of my custom S3 class and observe expected results when calling it
    my_custom_object <- my_custom_s3_class("hello", "world")
    my_custom_object
```

OUT:

```
hello world
```

IN:

```
# Attempt to append my custom S3 class to my list from before and observe no warnings or error messages
    my_list <- c(my_list, my_custom_object)


# Observe that it was not appended
    my_list
```

OUT:

```
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2
```

Comment: Don't use attributes to store the payload. Also, avoid using `cat` in a `print` method.

Comment: Thank you for the tips, @Roland. However, can you please provide a bit of rationale as to why or point me toward a link with rationale?

Specifically, what *should*  be included in attributes? 

And, if not in attributes, where should payload be stored?

Thanks again for your thoughtful input!

Comment: Well, store the payload in the list. There are several reason why you should try to avoid using the attributes for this if you can. Attributes might be stripped unintentionally, it's cumbersome to combine objects if you store the payload in the attributes, performance might be worse, ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object is of length 0

```
 length(my_custom_object)
[1] 0
```

so we need to wrap it in a `list`

```
c(my_list, list(my_custom_object))
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2

[[3]]
hello world
```

Comment: More importantly, the object is a list. Even if it was not an empty list, we would need to wrap with `list`. Check this out: `mylist <- list(1); c(mylist, as.POSIXlt(Sys.time()))`

Comment: @Roland Merci.  Bonjour!